# Photorealistic 3D Rendering solution for developers in the Cloud

Tags: 3d, cloud, 3d-rendering

What are some good alternatives to migenius for Photorealistic 3D Rendering solution for developers in the Cloud ? My focus is on following four components:
i) Ease of integration
ii) Cost
iii) Time to render the 3d model in image
iv) Quality of rendered image

My requirement is to render only one 3d model photorealistically into jpeg at a time, there's no rendering into video. I want the communication to happen via REST api.

Comment: Do you know Clara.io? https://clara.io/

Comment: I just checked. Where will I get the hardware information for their service ? I need that for estimating render time and quality